# React / Memo: Wrapping all the functional components with React.memo

Tags: reactjs

Thanks to React hooks, we started developing all the components as functional components. But we miss the PureComponent which avoided unnecessary rerenders. We used to create every component extending PureComponent.

My questions are: Shall we just blindly wrap all our functional components with React.memo? Will it slow down or affect the application in any way? Is there any situation where we should not wrap the functional components with React.memo?

Comment: please mark the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following links has the answer to my question.

https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14463

Answer (score 2):

Yes, React.memo, PureComponent and shouldComponentUpdate for classes can all have a negative performance effect as they carry a small calculation cost, so if you know your component is not a pure component you should be careful in how and when you use them.

Comment: I wonder in the case of **pure-components**, if those should **always** be wrapped with `React.memo` as a rule-of-thumb or the performance benefit doesn't worth it

Comment: Some reasons to opt out of using react memo might be:
 - You are sure that the component has a low rerender rate
- Your component is tiny (very little UI elements)
- Your components is usually provided with different props during rerenders (in this case prop comparsion is only a additional cost)
@vsync

Comment: I meant *pure* in the sense that it has no *props* at all, always returning the exact same output and the re-render rate is unknown, as that component might be used anywhere (for example - a specific one-element tooltip)

Comment: I think such components are quite rare, most components have at least some kind of props. Anyway, I would also say that such components should be wrapped in react.memo as there is no reason for them to be rerender and they will if their parents rerender. @vsync